# Xcode closing without saving

Tags: xcode

If I make a change to a Storyboard (e.g. delete a control) and then shut down Xcode, there is no prompt before saving; if I then reopen the file the control is still deleted; it is as if auto-saving is happening continuously. Is this normal behaviour or should I reinstall Xcode (ver 4.3.2, Lion, Mac Mini)

Comment: Mine does this too, I think this is normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of Lion OSX, your operating system continuously saves your documents.

- I always use time machine, when I work! It keeps me secure as if I
  want to travel in past and get my previously running version!

or

- you can always use git locally to save your source code safely.

Comment: Thanks owl; I have been searching for a guide on how to set up and use git with MonoDevelop. I have tried and have had confusing error messages (I come from a Windows background and have historically used Microsoft SourceSafe for source control)